# Flex - RegExp replace is not working using variable

Tags: regex, string, apache-flex, variables, replace

Must be simple fix but I cannot see for the life of me what I'm doing wrong.

I've tested the reg expression in an online tester and it works,
so assuming it's Flex dependent problem.

Here's my code and trace output - just trying to compact a string when I remove one element.

```
trace('Found Job To Delete:' + strJobToDelete);                         

strJobRegExp = "(" + strJobToDelete + "\\, )|(, " + strJobToDelete + ")|( " +  strJobToDelete + ")|(" + strJobToDelete + " )"
trace('Reg exp: ' + strJobRegExp);
findJobRegExp = new RegExp(strJobRegExp);                           
strJobNumList.replace(findJobRegExp, '');
trace('After Remove: ' + strJobNumList);
```

Here's the output:

> Found Job To Delete: 0007-13
>
> Reg exp: (0007-13\, )|(, 0007-13)|( 0007-13)|(0007-13 )
>
> After Remove: 0007-13, 0006-13
>
> After Edit ===> New Job: 0007-13, 0006-13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are matching with either space or space and comma, but not without any of them.

Try this pattern instead:

```
" 0007-13(?!,)|, 0007-13|0007-13,? |0007-13"
```

```
strJobRegExp = " #(?!,)|, #|#,? |#".replace(/#/g, strJobToDelete);
```

The `(?!,)` is a negative look-ahead, and says that there must not come a comma at the next position. It does not consume the character.

**Results:**

```
"0007-13"                     -> ""
"0007-13 0008-13"             -> "0008-13"
"0008-13 0007-13"             -> "0008-13"
"0007-13 0008-13 0009-13"     -> "0008-13 0009-13"
"0008-13 0007-13 0009-13"     -> "0008-13 0009-13"
"0008-13 0009-13 0007-13"     -> "0008-13 0009-13"
"0007-13, 0008-13"            -> "0008-13"
"0008-13, 0007-13"            -> "0008-13"
"0007-13, 0008-13, 0009-13"   -> "0008-13, 0009-13"
"0008-13, 0007-13, 0009-13"   -> "0008-13, 0009-13"
"0008-13, 0009-13, 0007-13"   -> "0008-13, 0009-13"
" 0007-13"                    -> ""
" 0007-13 0008-13"            -> " 0008-13"
" 0008-13 0007-13"            -> " 0008-13"
" 0007-13 0008-13 0009-13"    -> " 0008-13 0009-13"
" 0008-13 0007-13 0009-13"    -> " 0008-13 0009-13"
" 0008-13 0009-13 0007-13"    -> " 0008-13 0009-13"
" 0007-13, 0008-13"           -> " 0008-13"
" 0008-13, 0007-13"           -> " 0008-13"
" 0007-13, 0008-13, 0009-13"  -> " 0008-13, 0009-13"
" 0008-13, 0007-13, 0009-13"  -> " 0008-13, 0009-13"
" 0008-13, 0009-13, 0007-13"  -> " 0008-13, 0009-13"
"0007-13 "                    -> ""
"0007-13 0008-13 "            -> "0008-13 "
"0008-13 0007-13 "            -> "0008-13 "
"0007-13 0008-13 0009-13 "    -> "0008-13 0009-13 "
"0008-13 0007-13 0009-13 "    -> "0008-13 0009-13 "
"0008-13 0009-13 0007-13 "    -> "0008-13 0009-13 "
"0007-13, 0008-13 "           -> "0008-13 "
"0008-13, 0007-13 "           -> "0008-13 "
"0007-13, 0008-13, 0009-13 "  -> "0008-13, 0009-13 "
"0008-13, 0007-13, 0009-13 "  -> "0008-13, 0009-13 "
"0008-13, 0009-13, 0007-13 "  -> "0008-13, 0009-13 "
" 0007-13 "                   -> " "
" 0007-13 0008-13 "           -> " 0008-13 "
" 0008-13 0007-13 "           -> " 0008-13 "
" 0007-13 0008-13 0009-13 "   -> " 0008-13 0009-13 "
" 0008-13 0007-13 0009-13 "   -> " 0008-13 0009-13 "
" 0008-13 0009-13 0007-13 "   -> " 0008-13 0009-13 "
" 0007-13, 0008-13 "          -> " 0008-13 "
" 0008-13, 0007-13 "          -> " 0008-13 "
" 0007-13, 0008-13, 0009-13 " -> " 0008-13, 0009-13 "
" 0008-13, 0007-13, 0009-13 " -> " 0008-13, 0009-13 "
" 0008-13, 0009-13, 0007-13 " -> " 0008-13, 0009-13 "
```

Comment: My string is always is the format ####-##, ####-##, ####-## or no comma and just one space The example string is 0007-13, 0006-13 - and nothing is removed - and the target number can be in start position, end position or in a middle position

Comment: Thanks - looks perfect to me - I'll give it a shot in Flex

Comment: Nope - same issue - str.replace is doing nothing. <br/>`trace('Found Job To Delete: ' + strJobToDelete + " in list of jobs: " + strJobNumList); <br/>      
strJobRegExp = " " + strJobToDelete + "(?!,)|, " + strJobToDelete + "|" + strJobToDelete + ",? |" + strJobToDelete;
trace('RegExp: ' + strJobRegExp);<br/>
findJobRegExp = new RegExp(strJobRegExp); <br/>    
strJobNumList.replace(findJobRegExp,  '');<br/>
trace('After Remove: ' + strJobNumList);`<br/>Found Job To Delete: 0007-13
Reg exp:  0007-13(?!,)|, 0007-13|0007-13,? |0007-13< br/>
After Remove: 0004-13, 0006-13, 0007-13

Comment: `strJobNumList.replace` *returns* the updated string. It does not *modify* the string.

Comment: That's it - soooo obvious but it took me till midnight last night to find it. Thanks Markus